# htaccess rewriterule not working for old urls for site rebuild

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am struggling to get the rewrite rules working in .htaccess for search links on a property rental website I am working on.

The old links are like this:

```
example.com/index.php?proptype=Villa&action=search
```

and the new search link equivalent will be like this:

```
example.com/listing?holidaytype=Villa
```

Before I tried with wildcards I wanted to test with a set parameter. I have tried both of the following approaches but neither works.

```
RewriteRule index.php?proptype=Villa&action=search listing?holidaytype=Villa [L]
```

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^proptype=Villa&action=search$
RewriteRule ^index.php listing?holidaytype=Villa [L]
```

The only lines above these in my .htaccess file are as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Having checked a number of other related questions here and on other rewrite guidelines, I still can't get the rules working.  What have I missed - or could it be another problem?

Graham

Comment: What happens exactly? `/listing?holidaytype=Villa` - A URL like this is unlikely to map directly to the filesystem so there must be some other processing going on here? Does this map to `listing.php` perhaps?

Comment: I am not the main developer on this rebuild and am just looking at the redirects from the old/existing site, but yes that link `/listing?...`does seem to open listing.php - or possibly another file with handles the parameters first.

Comment: Is `Villa` a dynamic string that should be copied from the old URL to the new?

Answer (score 1):

If you are "redirecting" old URLs then you should implement an *external redirect*, not an *internal rewrite*, as you have done here. (`listing?holidaytype=Villa` is unlikely to be a valid filesystem path - but that's possibly another issue.)

For example, try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^proptype=Villa&action=search$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /listing?holidaytype=Villa [R=302,L]
```

This is a temporary (302) redirect, only change it to a permanent (301) when you are sure it's working OK.